# Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function at HTMLDocument.iniciar

Tags: javascript, ajax

Al iniciar me aparece este error

> Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function at HTMLDocument.iniciar

```
$(document).ready(iniciar)

function iniciar(){
$.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"../modelos/sucursales.php",
        success:function(datos){
            $(".sucursal").html(datos);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

El error es porque seguro estás usando la versión `slim` de JQuery , debes ir al [`CDN`](https://code.jquery.com/) y utilizar otra opción comprimida o no , menos `slim` , ya que está tiene opciones limitadas dentro del código una de ellas, `Ajax`

**V3.**

```
<script
 src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
 integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
 crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

**V2.**

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: pero ya he utilizado anteriormente ajax y no me habia dado problema alguno

Comment: @JUANCAMILORUIZRAMIREZ ¿Está utilizando la versión Slim? ¿No tuvo problemas con esta versión con respecto a Ajax ?.

Comment: pues antes no tuve problemas con ello

Comment: jajaj claroo. emm acabo de actualizar el jquery por el 3.3.1 y continua el error

Comment: @JUANCAMILORUIZRAMIREZ es raro que persista su error , simulé su pregunta y código, y funciona correctamente con las dos versiones de mi respuesta.

Comment: https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js mire descargue este jquery, el mismo obviamente hice los cambios en los archivos y carpetas correspondientes pero el error persiste

Comment: @JUANCAMILORUIZRAMIREZ te deje una respuesta que a me me funciona correctamente... he incluyo el jquery que use para el ejemplo...

Answer (score 0):

no se si tiene que ver con el hecho de que estas metiendo dentro del ready la funcion, pero este ejemplo a mi localmente me funciona, pero stackoverflow tiene politicas de cors que no me permiten ejecutar el sniped correctamnte...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    window.iniciar();
});
function iniciar(){
$.ajax({
        url: "https://xhero1.000webhostapp.com/favicon.ico",
        success:function(datos){
            console.log(datos);
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```